# Angular2 Webpack - compile sass files and output to a css using extract-text-webpack-plugin

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I have been trying to solve this issue for a while. By default my sass files are bundled to javascript files. I want to generate a css file.

Trying to use extract-text-webpack-plugin. Using webpack 2.1.0-beta.22.

**Code in my webpack.common.js**

```
   /*
    * SASS loader
    *
    */
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
        loader: "css-loader"
      })
    },



plugins: [
  new ExtractTextPlugin('app.css'),
  ...
  ...
```

When I run my application, it shows no error, only one in chrome **("Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.")**

Does any had a similar problem to this? Been trying a lot different loaders, but none had worked so far.

Comment: I have the same issues. Have you managed how to make it work?